# If it is possible to linearize no-else if statement as MIP constraint?

Tags: linear-programming

Assume that I have the following constraint:

```
IF d == 1 THEN x >= 1;

d : binary

x : integer
```

but there is no else, means that `IF d == 0`, there will be no constraint for x.

Is such constraint convertable to MIP linear constraint?

Comment: Is there a logical lower limit to `x` in this scenario?  0?  -1000?  Or is `x` truly unconstrained?

Comment: This is not suitable for Stack Overflow and needs to be moved to Operations Research

Comment: if `x` is non-negative then write: `x >= d`. If `x` can be negative, e.g. `x >= L` with `L < 0`. then write `x >= d + L(1-d)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be generally modelled in mixed integer programming with a "[Big M Constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method)":

```py
from pulp import *

d = LpVariable("d", cat='Binary')
x = LpVariable("x", lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

M = 100000

constraint = x >= 1 - M * (1 - d)
```

If `d==1` it turns into `x>=1`, else it's `x>=1-M` where M is a suitably chosen large number.

Answer (score -1):

`d <= x` if x is nonnegative integer.

`L(1-d)+d <= x` if `L<=x` where `L` is the lower bound of `x`

Comment: This is incorrect. For `d=1` we have `L(1-d) <= x ==> 0 <= x`  instead of `x>=1`. Better is `x >= d + L(1-d)`.

Comment: Corrected it now